# Can $z^*$ be represented using a formula made of elementary functions of $z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, elementary-functions

Let $z$ be a complex number, and $z^*$ be the complex conjugate. Is it possible to write $z^*$ in terms of $z$ while only using elementary functions like polynomial terms (complex exponents are allowed), exponentials, logarithms and such.

So, $z^* = z - 2\operatorname{Im}(z)$ is not allowed because $\operatorname{Im}(z) = (z - z^*)/2i$ references $z^*$ also and this would be circular. However, if you can write $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ as a formula of $z$ without referring to $z^*$ then, this would be okay.

Similarly, $z^* = |z|^2 /z$ is not allowed less you can write $|z|^2$ in the same way requested above (without referring to $z^*$ itself).

I have an intuitive feeling that this is not possible but can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: No, because $z\mapsto \overline z$ is not analytic.

Comment: I doubt it, because if $z^*$ could be written as a polynomial/rational function/exponential involving $z$, then it would mean that $z \mapsto z^*$ would be complex differentiable, however it is not

Comment: Short answer: no, because all your “elementary functions” are holomorphic [read: differentiable in the complex sense/can be written as power series] (or can be defined holomorphically on small open sets), while complex conjugation is not.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I knew I was forgetting something obvious from complex analysis to figure this out. I feel dumb, haha. Please feel free to write this out in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, principally because elementary functions and compositions, sums, and products thereof are complex differentiable, whereas the map taking $z$ to $z^*$ is not complex differentiable since, for instance, if we try to differentiate at $0$ we see that
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z^*}z$$
does not exist, since this quantity is $-1$ everywhere on the imaginary axis and $1$ everywhere on the real axis, so lacks a limit at $0$. Indeed, $z^*$ is not complex differentiable anywhere, so you can't even write it in elementary terms on any open set.